# C : how to solve the problem between system("clear") and strtok function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I am working on a calculator in which I want to extract parts from a string in the form:  (the underscore represents the space key).
I have a "segmentation fault" problem when I try to flush my terminal display. I think I found the epicenter of the problem which is the line :

```
ptr = strtok_r(EXPRESSION, " \\n", &context);
```

but I don't know how I could solve it without redoing the strtok function.

Do you have any solution to propose to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    #ifndef SWITCH_H
    #define SWITCH_H
        #define SWITCH(X)   for (char* __switch_p__ = X, __switch_next__=1 ; __switch_p__ ; __switch_p__=0, __switch_next__=1) { {
        #define CASE(X)   } if (!__switch_next__ || !(__switch_next__ = strcmp(__switch_p__, X))) {
        #define DEFAULT   }}
    #endif

int main()
{

   char EXPRESSION[22];
   char EXP1[10][1];
   char EXP2[10][1];
   char OPE[2][1];
   char* ptr;
   char* context = NULL;
   if ( fgets(EXPRESSION, sizeof EXPRESSION, stdin) )
    { 
        SWITCH (EXPRESSION)
    {
        CASE ("quit")
            return 0;
            break;
        CASE ("flush")
            system("clear");
            break;
        DEFAULT
            break;
    }

        ptr = strtok_r(EXPRESSION, " \n", &context);
        strcpy(EXP1[0], ptr); // Copy to token list
        ptr = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &context);
        strcpy(OPE[0], ptr); // Copy to token list
        ptr = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &context);
        strcpy(EXP2[0], ptr); // Copy to token list

        printf("%s %s %s\n", EXP1, OPE, EXP2);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve the problem with strtok :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#ifndef SWITCH_H
    #define SWITCH_H
        #define SWITCH(X)   for (char* __switch_p__ = X, __switch_next__=1 ; __switch_p__ ; __switch_p__=0, __switch_next__=1) { {
        #define CASE(X)   } if (!__switch_next__ || !(__switch_next__ = strcmp(__switch_p__, X))) {
        #define DEFAULT   }}
    #endif




int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        char EXPRESSION[22],EXP1[10],EXP2[10],OPE[1];
        
        if ( fgets(EXPRESSION, sizeof EXPRESSION, stdin) )
        {
            static const char DELIMITERS[] = " \n";
            int COUNTER = 0;
            char *ptr= strtok(EXPRESSION, DELIMITERS);
            SWITCH (ptr)
            {
                CASE ("quit")
                    return 0;
                    break;
                CASE ("flush")
                    system("clear");
                    break;
                DEFAULT
                    break;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<strlen(ptr);i++)
            {
                EXP1[i]=ptr[i];
            }

            COUNTER++;

            while ( ptr)
            {
                ptr= strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS);

                if(COUNTER==1)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<strlen(ptr);i++)
                    {
                        OPE[i]=ptr[i];
                    }
                }

                if(COUNTER==2)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<strlen(ptr);i++)
                    {
                        EXP2[i]=ptr[i];
                    }
                }

                COUNTER++;
            }
                }
}
```

But also by using argc , argv (it doesn't answer my initial project but I tried anyway).

I also tried to make my own extract part function, but I quickly gave up the idea because it causes stack overflow and segmentation fault. (sorry, I didn't have the idea to keep this code)

Comment: I want to extract parts from a string in the form:
[expression1]_[operator]_[expression2]
 (the underscore represents the space key)

Comment: `printf("%s %s %s\n", EXP1, OPE, EXP2);` should be `printf("%s %s %s\n", EXP1[0], OPE[0], EXP2[0]);` but seems to work.  Not seeing a problem with your use of strtok.

Comment: The problem is not there, it's when I write "flush" to call system("clear"), it creates a segmentation fault instead of cleaning my terminal (i'm on ubuntu).

Comment: Normally, the whole system is in a "while(1)" loop and when I type "flush", it is supposed to clean my terminal without leaving the program.

Comment: Your macros are not detecting "flush" so you are attempting to call strtok 3 times when you only have 1 token.

Comment: i tried with this, still on same error :
```
ptr = strtok_r(EXPRESSION, " \n", &context);
         if (strcmp( ptr, "quit" ) == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        if (strcmp( ptr, "flush" ) == 0)
            {
                system("clear");
            }
```

Comment: So it clears and then still does 2 more strtoks?

Comment: You are right but how can i fix it ?

Comment: i found the solution, i just need to put a flag in flush condition.

Thank you stark !!